# Stata: Checking for equality across different variables within a group

Tags: stata

I have a dataset divided into groups, and I want to check to make sure that the groups cannot be further divided into distinct subgroups.  Each observation in the group has a unique `ID` and another variable called `match_ID`, which for a two-member group is the ID number for the other observation in the group.  For groups with more than two members, the ID is repeated once for every match, so a three-member group would have all three ID's listed twice: once for each match.

Example of a two-member group:

```
 ID     match_ID group_ID
 1      2        55
 2      1        55
```

Example of a three-member group:

```
 ID    match_ID group_ID
 1     2        99
 1     3        99
 2     1        99
 2     3        99
 3     1        99
 3     2        99
```

My plan was to take the first `ID` in each group and make sure it appears as the `match_id` value for all the other members of the group.  If it does not, then the group contains a distinct subgroup. But this will only work for two-member groups (which cannot contain a subgroup anyway), so I think there needs to be a condition that the `ID` be checked against the `match_ID`'s for each *unique* `ID` within the group.  But I am not sure how to code this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understant what you ask. You say: "I want to check to make sure that the groups cannot be further divided into distinct subgroups". How is that reflected in the example data you provide? How does that relate to your question title? What code have you tried? I'm quite lost with your request.

Comment: I created these groups based on matching several other variables that are not listed.  I now am trying to do a check that my grouping algorithm was correct, and I thought the simplest way to do so would be to make sure that the group's first ID matched to the match_IDs for the rest of the group.  If it doesn't, then I have false positives in the group and these false positives would be their own subgroup.  I did the original matching in SAS but I received a request to do this part in STATA, which I am new to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any coding effort.

Comment: Is this data for some social network analysis? Do you care to show us an example of what a distinct subgroup would look like? Meanwhile, `bysort group_ID: assert ID[_N]*(ID[_N]-1)==_N` would at least make sure every group has n*(n-1) observations.

Comment: It is not for network analysis. And the subgroup bit isn't vital to the test, all I need is to be able to run the value in the ID column against the match_ID column and make sure there is a match.  To do this I simply did: gen groupflag=0; replace groupflag=1 if ID=F.match_ID. (I put the data into a panel with xtset using a simple count as the "date" so I could do L. and F. operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xtset` code did not work for me--maybe I was missing something. Anyway, here is a (rather ugly) code that counts the number of matches for each combination of `ID` and `match_ID` in each group, and reports results when the count is not exactly one.

```
// a program to run matches with by-groups
capture program drop match
program match, byable(recall)
marksample touse
preserve
qui drop if !`touse'
loca n=_n
loca N=_N
forval i=`n'/`N'    {
    qui count if (ID[`i']==match_ID[_n] & match_ID[`i']==ID[_n] & `i'!=_n)
    if (`r(N)'!=1)  {
            loca n=obs[`i']
            di "obs=`n' find `r(N)' matches"
        }   
    }
restore
end

// fake example
clear
input ID match_ID group_ID
1 2 10
1 3 10
2 1 10
2 3 10
3 1 10
3 2 10
1 2 11
1 3 11
2 1 11
2 3 11
3 1 11
1 1 12
1 3 12
2 1 12
2 3 12
3 1 12
3 2 12
end

sort group_ID ID match_ID
gen obs=_n // unique identifier
list // no matches for obs=10, 12, and 14
by group_ID: match
```

This does the job, but there are definitely ways to improve on this code--I had to resort to `preserve` and `restore` because I could not get the indexing to work. I'd also imagine something using `xtset` or `reshape` could be faster as row-wise operation is slow in Stata.